# Deploying nodejs code on amazon ec2-instance with jenkins

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, aws-code-deploy

I am creating a job which would deploy the code on ec2 instance and there I would like to run some test cases on it with jenkins.

Till now I have configured git with jenkins and able to take checkout of the code and now I would like to deploy the code on ec2 instance.

How Do I go about it? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can use AWS CodeDeploy for this

Comment: AWS CodeDeploy deploys the code on s3 bucket but I want it as a directory in my instance.

Comment: Code deploy retrieves the build package from s3 bucket and deploys on EC2 instance. The Jenkins can create build package and upload to s3 and code deploy can deploy it on ec2